# unfortunately app has stopped - cordova - plugin - camera

Tags: android, cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

I am trying to capture image from camera in my cordova application

```
 <div onclick="getImage();">
    <img width="60" height="60" id="img0" />
</div>
```

my getImage function

```
function getImage() 
{
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onCaptureTaskPhoto, onFail, {quality: 25,targetWidth: 512, destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI, correctOrientation: true});
}
```

my onCaptureTaskPhoto function

```
function onCaptureTaskPhoto(fileURI) 
{     
   var image1=document.getElementById('img0');
   image1.src =fileURI;
   image1.width="80";
   image1.height="80";
}
```

Now sometimes i can able to capture the image and put it in src of img. And sometimes its showing exception. and the application will be `unfortunately app has stopped`.

Internal storage of phone is 400MB.
This is the exception i am getting

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13231): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to resume activity {com.app/com.app.MainActivity}:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null,
request=34, result=-1, data=null} to activity
{com.app/com.app.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: here your result is **null** & you are trying to convert that **null** variable into `String`.

Comment: in what condition i have to check that if i am sending actual string or is it null?

Comment: can you please provide MainActivity code.

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete  process how to use camera in ionic...

first of all add camera plugin into your project:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

**services.js Code**

```
    .factory('Camera', function($q) {

   return {
      getPicture: function(options) {
         var q = $q.defer();

         navigator.camera.getPicture(function(result) {
            q.resolve(result);
         }, function(err) {
            q.reject(err);
         }, options);

         return q.promise;
      }
   }

});
```

**HTML Code**

```
    <button class = "button" ng-click = "takePicture()">Take Picture</button>
    <button class = "button" ng-click = "getPicture()">Open Gallery</button>
    <img ng-src = "{{user.picture}}">
```

**Controller Code**

```
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, Camera) {

   $scope.takePicture = function (options) {

      var options = {
         quality : 75,
         targetWidth: 200,
         targetHeight: 200,
         sourceType: 1
      };

      Camera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
         $scope.picture = imageData;;
      }, function(err) {
         console.log(err);
      });

   };

})
```